# Dynamic select box name as table value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<input type="hidden" name="arrco[0]" value="0">
<?php foreach ($ob->selectdata("select * from tb_attribute") as $key => $attributes) {
    ?>
    <td>
        <select name="<?php echo(strtolower($attributes['attribute_name'])); ?>[0]" class="form-control variation">
            <?php
            $prdvar = $ob->selectdata("select * from tb_variations where attr_id='" . $attributes['attr_id'] . "'");
            foreach ($prdvar as $variations) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo($variations['variations_name']); ?>"><?php echo($variations['variations_name']); ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Here select box name is table values, when i click on add more button it clone the entire row. its working perfectly.
But in my action page how can i save the posted values
arrco is the table count its value incremented in jquery

```
<?php
    extract($_POST);
    foreach($arrco as $key => $arrcoval)
    {
        foreach($arrco as $key => $arrcoval)
        {
            foreach($obsec->selectdata("select * from tb_attribute") as $key1 =>  $attributes)
            {
                $verat = ($_POST[strtolower($attributes['attribute_name'])][$key]);
                echo $key.'-'.$verat."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my table structure

```
Table tb_attribute

attr_id   | attribute_name
--------------------------
   1      |     Size
   2      |     Color

Table tb_variations

id  |  attr_id   |  variations_name
-----------------------------------
1   |    1       |       XL
2   |    1       |       SM
3   |    2       |       Red
4   |    2       |       Black


Now it shows

0-SM 
0-Red
1-XL
1-Black
2-XL
2-Red

But I want to show

0 - SM - Red
1 - XL - Black
2 - XL - Red
```

i enter 3 rows but its shows 6 times

Please help me

Comment: `foreach... select * ...` - you can see that this isn't very sensible, right?

Comment: I have created a working code, kindly explain your requirements here.
https://www.jdoodle.com/php-online-editor#&togetherjs=aik8F0Ngyc

Comment: @Strawberry, Do you have any other ideas (How can i get name with out select query)

Comment: @MilindSingh I cant see your code